# Rsync specific pattern, but exclude other files in same path

Tags: rsync

There are lots of files in `/dapp/parsD/parsapp/object`.  I only want to `rsync` the files in this directory that match **.sql*, **.pl* and **.sh*, but I also want to exclude 2 specific patterns in the same directory that end in *.sh*.

Is this possible? I am running **HP-UX 11i** on both source and destination. `rsync` version is *3.1.0*.

The below may be easier to visualize.  On the dev server, the '*x*' or '*X*' is replaced by '*d*' or '*D*', and on production server, it will be '*p*' or '*P*'.

Include the following files:

```
/xapp/parsX/parsapp/object/*.sql
/xapp/parsX/parsapp/object/*.pl
/xapp/parsX/parsapp/object/*.sh
```

But exclude the following files:

```
 /xapp/parsX/parsapp/object/getbackdate*autosys.sh
 /xapp/parsX/parsapp/object/parssendevent*.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` include/exclude/filter rules can be a pain to work with, but are ultimately very flexible. Here is one way to do what you want:

```
rsync --include-from=- /xapp/parsX/parsapp/object/ dest_dir <<EOF
- getbackdate*autosys.sh
- parssendevent*.sh
+ *.sql
+ *.pl
+ *.sh
- *
EOF
```

The `--include-from` makes `rsync` read the patterns from `stdin`, without this you could specify each pattern as a separate `--include` or `--exclude` option. You can also put the rules in a file and specify the name or use `-F` to make `rsync` look for a `.rsync-filter` file in each directory it reads.

Note also that the order of the patterns is also significant. Files are included/excluded according to the first pattern that matches them. Also, the `- *` rule at the end is necessary to make include rules work since everything is included by default. However this can be problematic with recursive transfers since it excludes all directories not explicitly included. One way around this is to include a `+ **/` rule to include all directories.